# Context of This Keyword with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, http, request, this, arrow-functions

I was learning to make HTTP requests in JS using XMLHTTpRequests. I know this method is not used much. but I have a doubt regarding this.

When I am using arrow functions in addEventListener then its console logging me undefined.

As arrow functions don't have its own **This** context so it takes it from its parent.So why exactly here it's not working?

Is my concept about it is wrong?

```js
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log(this.responsetext); // undefined
});
oReq.addEventListener("error", () => {
  console.log("error");
});
oReq.open("GET", "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/");
oReq.send();
console.log("Request Send");
```

Comment: Try this: `window.name="I am the window";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log(this.name)
});
` and you will understand

Comment: Now change to `console.log(oReq.response);` and it works